# How to reset / not preserve state for some properties in vuex store after redirection (ssr)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

We are using server-side rendering and are using `preserveState` for all our vuex modules to persist the state when navigating from one page to the next.

However, we have a specific store wherein we don't want to persist *some* properties. Is there a way to achieve this in Vuex store?  E.g.

```
@Module({ namespaced: true, dynamic: true, store, name, preserveState: true })
class SampleModule extends VuexModule {
      propertyOne: {}; // we want to persist this
      propertyTwo: {}; // we want to persist this
      propertyThree: {}; // we DO NOT want to persist this
      propertyThree: {}; // we DO NOT want to persist this
}
```

The only way we can think of for now is to create a separate store for those properties we don't want to persist. But this is not ideal as these properties are quite related and that the only difference is whether or not we want to persist them.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes the current way it's being handle in my recent project is to create an action which takes a payload that will be use to mutate the state back to it's default value whenever I redirect to another page..usually I'll suggest you called such action inside the destroy life cycle hook of the components unloaded when you redirect to another page. Another method I know of is to use vuex subscribe method...https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribe. This may seem like an over kill but it can also work depending on your needs.
If I have some time tomorrow, I may attach some code samples for you to look at.. apologies, it's 3am and I just gotta sleep....ciao